# tflearn conv2d_transpose shape incompatibility

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn, deconvolution

I am giving image of size [256 256 3] as input and want output of same size but the below mention error is showing. I have tried changing the shapes, filter, strides nothing is working. Any other method of achieving the same will be appreciated or link to something same as above, input and output both are image.
this is my code :

```
enter code here
import tensorflow as tf 
import tflearn
import os

import numpy as np
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d,conv_2d_transpose
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
import loaddata

LR = 1e-3
MODEL_NAME = 'deblurr-{}-{}.model'.format(LR, '2conv-basic')
IMG_SIZE = 256
strides = [1,2,2,1]


convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3],dtype=tf.float32, 
name='input')
print ("convnet :" , convnet.shape)


convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 6, 5,strides=strides, activation='LeakyReLU')
print ("convnet :" , convnet.shape)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet,12, 5,strides=strides, activation='LeakyReLU')
print ("convnet :" , convnet.shape)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 24, 5,strides=strides, activation='LeakyReLU')
print ("convnet :" , convnet.shape)


convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 48, 5,strides=strides, activation='LeakyReLU')
print ("convnet :" , convnet.shape)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 24, 5,strides=strides, activation='LeakyReLU')
print ("convnet :" , convnet.shape)

convnet = conv_2d_transpose(convnet, 12, 5,output_shape=
[64,64,12],strides=strides, activation='tanh')
print ("convnet :" , convnet.shape)
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)
print ("convnet :" , convnet.shape)

convnet = conv_2d_transpose(convnet, 6, 5,output_shape=
[128,128,6],strides=strides, activation='tanh')
print ("convnet :" , convnet.shape)
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)
print ("convnet :" , convnet.shape)

convnet = conv_2d_transpose(convnet, 3, 5,output_shape=
[256,256,3],strides=strides, activation='tanh')
print ("convnet :" , convnet.shape)
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)
print ("convnet :" , convnet.shape)

convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, 
loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')
print ("convnet :" , convnet.shape)

model = tflearn.models.dnn.DNN(convnet)

if os.path.exists('{}.meta'.format(MODEL_NAME)):
model.load(MODEL_NAME)
print('model loaded!')

y_train, x_train = loaddata.load_data(data_type='train')


X = x_train
Y = y_train

y_test, x_test = loaddata.load_data(data_type='test')

test_x = y_test
test_y = x_test

model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=10, validation_set=({'input': 
test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), batch_size=2,
snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

and the error coming as this:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py in merge_with(self, other)
    562         for i, dim in enumerate(self._dims):
--> 563           new_dims.append(dim.merge_with(other[i]))
    564         return TensorShape(new_dims)

C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py in merge_with(self, other)
    137     other = as_dimension(other)
--> 138     self.assert_is_compatible_with(other)
    139     if self._value is None:

C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py in assert_is_compatible_with(self, other)
    110       raise ValueError("Dimensions %s and %s are not compatible" % (self,
--> 111                                                                     other))
    112

ValueError: Dimensions 32 and 8 are not compatible

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
E:\extra\notes\New folder\source\models.py in <module>()
     53 print ("convnet :" , convnet.shape)
     54
---> 55 model = tflearn.models.dnn.DNN(convnet)
     56
     57 if os.path.exists('{}.meta'.format(MODEL_NAME)):

C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py in __init__(self, network, clip_gradients, tensorboard_verbose, tensorboard_dir, checkpoint_path, best_checkpoint_path, max_checkpoints, session, best_val_accuracy)
     63                                max_checkpoints=max_checkpoints,
     64                                session=session,
---> 65                                best_val_accuracy=best_val_accuracy)
     66         self.session = self.trainer.session
     67

C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py in __init__(self, train_ops, graph, clip_gradients, tensorboard_dir, tensorboard_verbose, checkpoint_path, best_checkpoint_path, max_checkpoints, keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours, random_seed, session, best_val_accuracy)
    129                 train_op.initialize_training_ops(i, self.session,
    130                                                  tensorboard_verbose,
--> 131                                                  clip_gradients)
    132
    133             # Saver for saving a model

C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py in initialize_training_ops(self, i, session, tensorboard_verbose, clip_gradients)
    695             # Compute gradients operations
    696             with tf.control_dependencies([loss_avg_op, acc_avg_op]):
--> 697                 self.grad = tf.gradients(total_loss, self.train_vars)
    698                 if clip_gradients > 0.0:
    699                     self.grad, self.grad_norm = \

C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py in gradients(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gate_gradients, aggregation_method)
    560             if (isinstance(in_grad, ops.Tensor) and
    561                 t_in.dtype != dtypes.resource):
--> 562               in_grad.set_shape(t_in.get_shape())
    563             _SetGrad(grads, t_in, in_grad)
    564         if loop_state:

C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in set_shape(self, shape)
    376         this tensor.
    377     """
--> 378     self._shape = self._shape.merge_with(shape)
    379
    380   @property

C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py in merge_with(self, other)
    564         return TensorShape(new_dims)
    565       except ValueError:
--> 566         raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are not compatible" % (self, other))
    567
    568   def concatenate(self, other):

ValueError: Shapes (?, 32, 32, 24) and (?, 8, 8, 24) are not compatible
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the shape output from your conv layers:

```
convnet1: (?, 256, 256, 3)
convnet2: (?, 128, 128, 6)
convnet3: (?, 64, 64, 12)
convnet4: (?, 32, 32, 24)
convnet5: (?, 16, 16, 48)
convnet6: (?, 8, 8, 24)
convnet7: (?, 64, 64, 12)
convnet8: (?, 128, 128, 6)
convnet9: (?, 256, 256, 3)
convnet10: (?, 256, 256, 3)
```

From convnet5 to convnet6 you want to upscale your dimensions with a factor of 8. But your code you only upscale with a factor of 2 in your strides:

```
strides = [1,2,2,1]
convnet = conv_2d_transpose(convnet, 12, 5,output_shape=
          [64,64,12],strides=strides, activation='tanh')
```

The shape of gradient that is being backpropagated, are not compatible with this layer. But if you just change this line to:

```
convnet = conv_2d_transpose(convnet, 12, 5,output_shape=
          [64,64,12],strides=[1,8,8,1], activation='tanh')
```

Then your code should work.

Comment: how to  calculate scale up given two layers and vice versa?

Comment: If your input shape is [?,H1,W1,?] and you what your output shape to be [?,H2,W2,?] then your strides should be [1,H2/H1,W2/W1,1]